# How to target dynamically UI elements created with common.js with Appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, commonjs, appcelerator-alloy

I am using Alloy and normally target an element in ui.xml with the contoller easily:

ui.xml

```
<Label id ="block1">
```

controller.js

```
$.block1.backgroundColor = "red";
```

But how can **I target UI elements that are created within the controller filer** (outside the function that creates the elements)? In particular, how can I later and dynamically set the background color of block2 to "green" when the elements are created by the for loop?

`$.block2.backgroundColor = "green";` does not work as the element is not in the .xml file

```
function createBlocks(){
    for (i=0;i<=27;i++){
        var block = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            id: "block"+ i,
            backgroundColor: "red",
            text: i,
            width: 10,
            left: 2 + (10 * i),
        });
        $.hammerListStats.add(block);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `block` elements you are creating only life under that name inside the loop. You either need to store them in an array or use `$.hammerListStats.children` ot access them.

So either create an empty array before the loop `var elements = []`, use `elements.push(block)` inside the loop and use `elements[0].text=...` to change the text.

Or just use `$.hammerListStats.children[0].text = ...` to access them. This works fine as long as you don't have any other components inside `$.hammerListStats` or if you know their position you just add the value to it.

Comment: thanks. that did the trick. the brackets were too much $.hammerListStats.children[0].text =

Comment: you are correct, thanks! you can use `getChildren()[]` and then you'll need the brackets. I've corrected the example

Answer (score 0):

Elsewhere in your code you should be able to do something like this...

```
var i = 1;
var mytext = $["block"+ i].text;
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. This works and i can dynamically target them - but only when the label block is in the xml file. When the labels are created in the .js file targetting it like $["block"+i].backgroundColor = "orange"; gives me an undefined is not an object error. Ideally, I'd not put the 28 labels in the xml file. Ill accept this as corect when no other suggestions are posted